# how to use rdtscp correctly?

Tags: benchmarking, rdtsc

according to 《How to Benchmark Code Execution Times on Intel® IA-32 and IA-64 Instruction Set
Architectures》, i use code below:

```
static inline uint64_t bench_start(void)
{
    unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high;
    asm volatile("CPUID\n\t"
        "RDTSCP\n\t"
        "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
        "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
        : "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)
        ::"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");

    return (uint64_t) cycles_high << 32 | cycles_low;
}

static inline uint64_t bench_end(void)
{
     unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high;
     asm volatile("RDTSCP\n\t"
         "mov %%edx, %0\n\t"
         "mov %%eax, %1\n\t"
         "CPUID\n\t"
         : "=r" (cycles_high), "=r" (cycles_low)
         ::"%rax", "%rbx", "%rcx", "%rdx");
     return (uint64_t) cycles_high << 32 | cycles_low;
}
```

but in fact, I also see someone use code below:

```
static inline uint64_t bench_start(void)
{
   unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high;
   asm_volatile("RDTSCP\n\t"
                : "=d" (cycles_high), "=a" (cycles_low));
   return (uint64_t) cycles_high << 32 | cycles_low;
}

static inline uint64_t bench_start(void)
{
   unsigned cycles_low, cycles_high;
   asm_volatile("RDTSCP\n\t"
                : "=d" (cycles_high), "=a" (cycles_low));
   return (uint64_t) cycles_high << 32 | cycles_low;
}
```

as you know, RDTSCP is **pseudo serializing** ,why someone use the second code？two reasons I guess, below:

- Maybe in most situation, RDTSCP can ensure complete "in-order exectuion"?
- Maybe just want to avoid using CPUID for efficient?

Comment: I can't imagine how the second implementation can be justified due to the reason you have mentioned and stated in that Intel whitepaper. Also, the `rdtscp` in your bench_start() is redundant due to the previous cpuid call. You save a byte by just calling `rdtsc`, which is the way recommended in that awesome Intel whitepaper

Comment: **The second inline asm for `rdtscp` is unsafe.  It clobbers ECX without telling the compiler.**  Use a clobber, or better use the intrinsic. 
 [Get CPU cycle count?](//stackoverflow.com/a/51907627).  My answer on that Q&A also has some links to serializing before/after `rdtsc` with `lfence`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get CPU cycle count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772567/get-cpu-cycle-count)